# Does blur() in Android Webview work?

Tags: android, webview, blur

Quite simply, has anyone successfully used `HTMLElementObject.blur()` inside of an Android Webview? I am attempting to use it to release the focus on a text field in webview, and it is doing nothing. It's definitely possible I am calling it incorrectly, but webview has been really quirky for me and I'm wondering if anyone else has gotten it to work.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp is specifically what I'm talking about.